# Swift 3 Array Restrictions

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uibutton, swift3

Here is my code, right now 10 different buttons are being give names based off a function I created and this is working properly.

```
public func buttonNameSetAndColor(){
    let buttonNamesAndColor = [button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9, button10]

    for i in 0...9 {
        var val = NamePicker()
        buttonNamesAndColor[i]?.setTitle(val, for: .normal)
        buttonNamesAndColor[i]?.sizeToFit()

    }
}
```

What I now what to do is make this function a little bit more complex I thought about another for loop but that might be the hard way of doing things. What I want to try to do is to make it so that if out of the 10 buttons that if 3 or more have the same name that it will change one of the three to one of my other random names.

Im trying to implement this code inside of the for loop

```
        // array to find duplicates
        var buttonValues = [String]()
        buttonValues.insert(val, at: i)
        print(buttonValues[i])
```

but its giving array out of bounds errors

For example lets say I have these names (a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h)

```
button1 = a

button2 = a

button3 = a

button4 = b

button5 = b

button6 = c

button7 = c

button8 = b

button9 = f

button10 = e
```

I would like to have my new function fix button1-button3 and make one of those buttons a different name so there is only 2 buttons with the same name, also after that it would fix button4, button5, button8 and change one of their names as well without giving any on them a name that 2 buttons already have.

Any comments or suggestion about how I could accomplish this would be helpful.

Comment: This is a strange design... why would you want to do this?

Comment: Its just a problem i would like to figure out how to solve thats the point of coding is to figure out ways to solve problems. @AlexanderMomchliov

Comment: oh believe me, I know. My point is that I suspect this to be an xy problem http://xyproblem.info

Comment: it really isnt my question is pretty clear as is my problem @AlexanderMomchliov

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways (I'll delete this suggestion if so), but what about a dictionary **[String,UIButton]** for this?

```
var dict = [String:UIButton]()
setButtonTitle("a", newButton);

func setButtonTitle(title:String, button:UIButton) {
    var newTitle = ""
    if dict[title] == nil {
        dict[title] = button
    } else {
        newTitle = getNewTitle(button)
        dict[newTitle] = button
    }
}

func getNewTitle(button: UIButton) -> String {
    // code to find unique title
}
```

Comment: i understand what you are thinking with this code but this wouldnt work, i would need to have all the button names that are choosen in an array and then compare them all to find ones that are the same and replace them till it fits the requirements.

Comment: is there a way i could get this line of code that sets the title to be put into an array so it tells me the new array of title names? "buttonNamesAndColor[i]?.setTitle(NamePicker(), for: .normal)" @dfd

Comment: I guess I'm (very) unclear about what you are doing and why. You can have your UIButtons set up in an array, but (1) you probably want to do this entirely through code, and (2) you probably would be better off setting them up as a subview of something larger - think in terms of a UIToolbar, UINavigationBar, etc.